# What is this black I shaped line with serifs on my viewport?

Tags: interface

What is this black line in my viewport and how do I get rid of it?
[image]

It doesn't seem to be an object in the outliner as this line is still there even after I hide everything on the outliner.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you select it in Object mode by clicking on it, and does it then show up in the Outliner? - Press '.' (period/Del key on the numpad) while hovering over the outliner to show its entry there.

Comment: I can't select it in object mode. I tried hiding everything in the outliner, but it's still there. (question edited to show this)

Comment: I think you'll need to share your file assuming it's not too large so that someone can have a look at it. If it's smaller than 30Meg you can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to add the link to your question.

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. It's only in the 2D Animation viewport, and if you create a new one (new 2d animation tab), it's not there.

Comment: Very odd! I suspect it must be a bug but I don't usually use Grease pencil so don't know what to expect.. You can turn off all the viewport overlays, View Object Types and Gizmos and it still appears. Also I get brief psycedelic flashes of patterns in the sequencer window here as I reduce its height at the bottom of the viewport. Suggest you report it as a bug (Help > Report a Bug in Blender) including that Blend file in the report and let the developers work that one out!

Comment: The wierdest thing is, the line is not in the viewport. If you pull the border of the outliner through it, it will be on the outliner. The line will be on the same spot on the whole workspace, even if you change the Editor type. It looks like it stays at the center of the window if you resize it.

Comment: If I pull a border (between to editors) below the line and click a few times on it, it jumps a little bit to the left. I guess this is a border element which remained on the HUD accidentaly. So bug.

Comment: I voted to close as a bug ... but if you can't replicate the bug it wouldn't be accepted as a bug either. Probably as suggested by Christopher - delete this Workspace and add a new one ... try to forget :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the equivalent of the black border between editors you can drag to resize them or create new ones. It is an artifact from bugged workspace, producing leftover editor divider.

It doesn't show up if you disable *Load UI* from the file manager and open the file. It also doesn't show up in other workspaces if you change to *Rendering* or *Compositing* tab.

Doesn't seem to be mergeable with neighbouring areas, and "floats" above other editors in the *2D Animation* workspace, "bleeding" into other editors even if you cross it with an area divider.

If you drag it it initiates a failed area resize/merge operation, and if you <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> on it, it creates a new blank window, much like any other border would, except for the lack of content.

[image]

How did it happen? I don't know probably a bug or unforeseen corner case. Might be worth reporting if you can provide a file.

How to get rid of it? Either get rid of the bugged workspace and create a new one by deleting it, or open the file without the *Load UI* option turned on in the file manager side bar, then resave the file.

Comment: Thank you very much for the gif! I was thinking it was some measuring tool or ruler or something, but it was a buggy border line XD. I appreciate your and everybody's help on this!